# Highstock chart - missing data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm using highstock chart to display some data. I'm showing multiple series on the same chart but they don't start / end at the same time:

[image]

The problem is, if I navigate to some period of time where I have data for only one series (green one), everything disappears from the chart.

[image]

In this case, I should see the green line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is It possible to put your code on an [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I upgraded highstock chart from 1.3.7 to 1.3.10 and that solved the problem.